# What does it signify to have a value enclosed by angle brackets?

Tags: visible-light, electrons, electric-current, charge, notation

What is the significance of enclosing a value (say for instance, electric current $i$) by angle brackets instead of curly brackets?

I am currently reading a book and there is an equation which defines a photodector's (PIN PD) variance of quantum noise and is given by

\begin{equation}
    \sigma_{q-PIN}^{2} = 2q\langle i\rangle B,
    \label{equ:varPIN}
\end{equation}

where, $q$ is the electronic charge and $B$ is the bandwidth of the filter that follows the PD.

What I am battling with is understanding why $i$ (which I believe is the photo current generated by the PD) is enclosed by $\left<\right>$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add something to the Kyle Kanos's [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/516408/179151) and the belonging discussion:

In general the angle brackets denote an expectation value of a random variable $x(t)$. You can determine the expectation value of this variable by either averaging over time or by an average over an ensemble. The question if these two quantities are the same is related to ergodicity. Or more precisely, is it the same if I run an experiment for a long time or if I repeat the same experiment many times and then taking the average?

Let us approach these two types of averages in more detail:

**Ensemble average**

An ensemble is the countable collection of all possible realizations of $x(t)$. The ensemble average is then defined as averaging over all realizations $x_r(t)$ when the number of preparations $N$ approaches very lager numbers

$$
\langle x(t) \rangle = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{r=1}^N x_r(t).
$$

**Time average**

The time average is given by the average over time of the $k$-th realization of the previous ensemble

$$
\overline{x_k(t)} = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{t-T/2}^{t+T/2} x_k(t') dt'.
$$

This does  no longer depend on $t$ or $T$, but can in general still depend on the particular realization $x_k(t)$ of the ensemble.

In principle there can be as many different time averages as there are elements of the ensemble.

Comment: "Previous answer" could become confusing once more answers are added, so I have edited to explicitly reference Kyle's answer. Also, comments on posts can often become deleted once they are no longer needed, so I have removed references to comments on other posts in order to avoid possible future confusion. Physics SE is not a discussion forum, so ideally your answer should just stand on its own.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, the single variable surrounded by angled brackets denotes some sort of *mean value*. In this case, I suspect it might be with respect to time:
$$
\langle i\rangle\triangleq\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Ti(\tau)\,\mathrm{d}\tau
$$
where $T$ is the period. See [the Wikipedia entry on such brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Angle_brackets) for more.

Another alternative, though not likely in this case, is that a variable in angle brackets is an [*expectation value*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). For instance, given that $x$ follows some probability distribution function, $p(x)$, then we can define,
$$
\langle x\rangle\equiv\mathbb{E}(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} xp(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Or, similarly, for some stochastic process $x_t$, for instance the [*Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process)
$$
\mathbb{E}(x)=\langle x_t\rangle=\langle \theta(\mu- x_t)\,\mathrm{d}t+\sigma\,\mathrm{d}W_t\rangle=x_0e^{-\theta t}+\mu\left(1-e^{-\theta t}\right)
$$
for some [Wiener process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) $W_t$ and constants $\theta,\,\mu,\,\sigma$.

Comment: With reference to your answer, am I right to say that $\left(\tau\right) $ is an instance of time (many infinitesimal points in time)? I am merely trying to get my facts right, bear with me if this is such a trivial request for clarification.

Comment: @AllycanMapunda i intended on using $\tau$ to denote time instead of $t$ to reduce confusion, though i don't use $t$ anywhere, now that i look back on it...

Comment: In the usage I've seen, angle brackets usually denote an *expectation value* rather than a mean over time. The averaging might be done over an ensemble of executions of a measurement, rather than over time. The two kinds of averages will be the same in certain circumstances (time-invariant systems, I guess)  but not all circumstances.

Comment: @ThePhoton so basically you are agreeing with Kyle Kanos but under the condition that a system is time-invariant. So what I want to understand from your comment is that are you saying the mean over time is not the same as expectation value? If so, does this mean that the expectation value is only valid for one instant of time rather than instances of time?

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, that is another meaning, though I don’t think there’s much of a stochastic process in a current. When I get back to the computer, I can amend my answer

Comment: @AllycanMapunda, I think the new answer by Max Stammer has explained it better than I could. What I remember from coursework years ago is we use the over-bar ($\bar{x}$) for time averages and angle brackets ($<x>$) for ensemble averages. Max does a better job than I could explaining when they are different and when they are the same.